# How to restructure and map an array to fit into a specified data structure in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, mapping

I am using a reaviz is a charting tool for React. I am creating a habit tracker app and want to visually display the data on a series bar graph for the last week of user inputs. I have my data from my database in a structure like this:

```
habits = [
 { 
   habit: "Cook Dinner",
   inputs: [
     {
      input: 'Success',
      date: 'Oct 5th 21'
     },
     {
      input: 'Fail',
      date: 'Oct 6th 21'
     },
     {
      input: 'Skip',
      date: 'Oct 7th 21'
     }]
  },
  { 
   habit: "Clean House",
   inputs: [
     {
      input: 'Fail',
      date: 'Oct 5th 21'
     },
     {
      input: 'Fail',
      date: 'Oct 6th 21'
     },
     {
      input: 'Fail',
      date: 'Oct 7th 21'
    }]
  },
  { 
   habit: "Cook Dinner",
     inputs: [
     {
      input: 'Success',
      date: 'Oct 5th 21'
     },
     {
      input: 'Fail',
      date: 'Oct 6th 21'
     },
     {
      input: 'Skip',
      date: 'Oct 7th 21'
     }]
   }]
```

So now I would like to figure out a way to map my data to the data structure I need for the chart for example the output would be something like this for the above data. I will need to count how many inputs fall on that day for either, success, fail, or skip:

```
habitsMappedData = [
     {
    key: 'Oct 5th 21',
    data: [
      {
        key: 'Success',
        data: 2
      },
      {
        key: 'Fail',
        data: 1
      },
      {
        key: 'Skip',
        data: 0
      }
    ]
  },  {
    key: 'Oct 6th 21',
    data: [
      {
        key: 'Sucess',
        data: 0
      },
      {
        key: 'Fail',
        data: 3
      },
      {
        key: 'Skip',
        data: 0
      }
    ]
  },  {
    key: 'Oct 7th 21',
    data: [
      {
        key: 'Success',
        data: 0
      },
      {
        key: 'Fail',
        data: 1
      },
      {
        key: 'Skip',
        data: 2
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Really appreciate you taking a look through this. If any clarifications are required please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just a 'group-by' operation by date, but because of the nested arrays it's a little more involved.

The below snippet uses a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call to accumulate into an object using `date` as the grouping property, and summing using `input` as a secondary property. To convert the resulting object back to an array of nested objects it calls [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) on the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the returned object and maps the `key` and `data` properties using the `map` provided as the [second parameter of `Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#parameters). The nested `data` objects are generated using a final [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call.

```js
const habits = [ { habit: 'Cook Dinner', inputs: [ { input: 'Success', date: 'Oct 5th 21', }, { input: 'Fail', date: 'Oct 6th 21', }, { input: 'Skip', date: 'Oct 7th 21', }, ], }, { habit: 'Clean House', inputs: [ { input: 'Fail', date: 'Oct 5th 21', }, { input: 'Fail', date: 'Oct 6th 21', }, { input: 'Fail', date: 'Oct 7th 21', }, ], }, { habit: 'Cook Dinner', inputs: [ { input: 'Success', date: 'Oct 5th 21', }, { input: 'Fail', date: 'Oct 6th 21', }, { input: 'Skip', date: 'Oct 7th 21', }, ], }, ];

const habitsMappedData = Array.from(
  Object.entries(
    habits.reduce((a, { inputs }) => {
      for (const { date, input } of inputs) {
        (a[date] ??= { Success: 0, Fail: 0, Skip: 0 })[input] += 1;
      }

      return a;
    }, {})
  ),
  ([key, _data]) => ({
    key,
    data: Object.entries(_data).map(([key, data]) => ({ key, data })),
  })
);

console.log(habitsMappedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

*Note: the above relies on the [logical nullish assignment operator (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) which can be replaced with an `OR` short-circuit if needed for compatibility.*

```
for (const { date, input } of inputs) {
  (a[date] || (a[date] = { Success: 0, Fail: 0, Skip: 0 }))[input] += 1;
}
```

or written out explicitly in an `if`

```
for (const { date, input } of inputs) {
  if (a[date] === undefined) {
    a[date] = { Success: 0, Fail: 0, Skip: 0 };
  }
  a[date][input] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. You my friend are amazing. I learnt a lot from this. I greatly appreciate you taking the time to help me out on this.